# Splitting and plotting the values on a python graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

```
    show_id type    title   director    cast    country date_added  release_year
s17 Movie   Europe's Most Dangerous Man: Otto Skorzeny in Spain Pedro de Echave GarcÃ­a, Pablo AzorÃ­n Williams September 22, 2021 2020
```

Here is a one-row sample as a dict of lists:

```
{'show_id': ['s17'], 'type': ['Movie'], 'title': ["Europe's Most Dangerous Man: Otto Skorzeny in Spain"], 'director': ['Pedro de Echave García, Pablo Azorín Williams'], 'cast': [''], 'country': [''], 'date_added': ['September 22, 2021'], 'release_year': ['2020']}
```

I am working on the netflix dataset  to learn python. I have a dataframe like below, I am trying to split the directors into seperate rows so that i can plot a graph to analyze the number of films directed by a director in each year. I have tried the following code but it is throwing an error saying that column show_id is not found. Is there a better way to split  the director name to plot onto a graph:

```
df_new = df[['title','director']]
dfd = df_new['director'].str.split(',')
dfd = dfd.explode()
dfd = dfd.reset_index()
dfd.columns = ['show_id','director_1']
df.merge(dfd['show_id','director_1'], on = 'show_id' , how ='left')
```

Comment: The format of your *input/dataframe* is ambiguous and the country information seems to be missing. Can you make a reproducible example with `print(df.sample().to_dict("list"))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use [*this*](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivamb/netflix-shows) dataset to answer your question.

You can start by making a unique directors names with [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)/[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) :

```
df = (
        pd.read_csv("netflix_titles.csv").dropna(subset="director")
              .assign(director=lambda x: x["director"].str.split(r"\s*,\s*"))
              .explode("director")
)
```

Then use [`countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) from [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) tovisualize the number of films directed by a given director :

```
import seaborn as sns #pip install seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #pip install matplotlib

sns.set_style("darkgrid")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))

sns.countplot(x="release_year", hue="director", data=df[df["director"].eq("Raúl Campos")], ax=ax)

ax.set_xlabel("Year")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of Films Directed")

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```python
df = df[['title','director']]
dfd = df.director.str.split(',').explode().str.strip().to_frame().rename(columns={'director':'director_1'})
res = dfd.join(df)
```

Output:

```
               director_1                                              title                                       director
0  Pedro de Echave García  Europe's Most Dangerous Man: Otto Skorzeny in ...  Pedro de Echave García, Pablo Azorín Williams
0   Pablo Azorín Williams  Europe's Most Dangerous Man: Otto Skorzeny in ...  Pedro de Echave García, Pablo Azorín Williams
```

For the `join`, you can rely on the index labels of dfd (post-`explode`) to map to those of the original rows in df.